# Prove that the subtracting of two natural powers of 2 divisible by 57

Tags: combinatorics

I've got myself the next mathematical expression:

$$(2^n-2^k)/57$$

i need to prove that there are two natural numbers $n=k$ so that the equation gives an integer.
For now, i made a program [Not a clever one, Just brute-force], and found that $n=19$ and $k=1$ are correct for the equation.

But given the circumstances in which i don't have a program which does my combinatorics tests , How can i mathematically prove that?

Thanks.

Comment: When you say $n=k$ and $n=19$, $k=1$, I'm assuming the first equality should actually be $n\neq k$? Either way, it's clear the case $n=k$ can't happen.

Comment: Is it a plus as in the question or a minus as in the title?

Comment: And then $n = k$ is surely a misprint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the same as finding $2^n + 2^k \equiv 0 \pmod {57}$, which we can split into solving $\mod 3$ and $\mod 19$.

For mod 3 the powers of two are just 1 and 2, so $n\equiv 1 \pmod 2$, $k\equiv 2 \pmod 2$ will work.

For mod 19 there are quite a lot of options (18 of them) but the trick is to notice that $2^{\frac{19-1}{2}} \equiv -1 \pmod {19}$, then $2^a + 2^{a+9} \equiv 0$ for any $a \mod 18$.

Putting those together we get solutions $$\begin{array}{rcl} n &=& 2x+1 \\ k &=& 2(x+5)+18y \end{array}$$

Comment: If you wondered how will you notice that power of 2 is -1? The answer is quadratic reciprocity.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so the question is to find $n > k$ such that $57$ divides $2^{n} - 2^{k} = 2^{k} (2^{n-k} - 1)$, or
$$
2^{m} \equiv 1 \pmod{57},
$$
for $m = n - k > 0$.

So you are looking for the period $t$ of $2$ modulo $57$ (that is, the smallest such $m$), and then your $m$'s will be the multiples of $t$.

To compute $t$, you notice that $2$ is an element of the group $G$ of the invertible elements of $\mathbf{Z}_{57}$, so $t$ has to be a divisor of $\varphi(57) = \varphi(3 \cdot 19) = 2 \cdot 18 = 36$, which simplifies your calculations.

If you have to do it by hand, you would start computing $2^{36/2}$ and $2^{36/3}$ modulo $57$. Since the first one gives you $1$ already, you don't need to compute the other one, and are left with showing $2^{18/2}$ and $2^{18/3}$ are not congruent to $1$ modulo $57$, to get $t = 18$.

**PS** Since $57$ divides $2^{19} -2$ but not $2^{19} + 2$, I took the statement in the title to be the correct one.

Comment: First off, I'm sorry for not-replying faster.
I did mean 2^n-2^k.
I don't understand how you got from φ(3⋅19) to 2⋅18, Can you recall that?

Comment: @TheAlchemist, sure! $\varphi$ is Euler's Totient function. It has the property that $\varphi(p) = p - 1$ if $p$ is prime, and $\varphi(m n) = \varphi(m) \varphi(n)$ if $\gcd(m, n) = 1$. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_totient_function#Computing_Euler.27s_function

Answer (score 1):

Just a hint:

try to compute for which $m$, $57 | 2^m + 1$, then setting $m = n - k$ you have $57| 2^k (2^{n-k} + 1) = (2^n + 2^k)$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $n > k$, then $57 \mid 2^n + 2^k$ if and only if $57 \mid 2^{n - k} + 1$,
as $\gcd(57, 2^k) = 1$. Now $57 = 3 \cdot 19$, so $\phi(57) = 2 \cdot 18 = 36$. By Euler's theorem, $2^{36} \equiv 1 \pmod{57}$. A divisor of 36 should work, trying $2^{18} \equiv 1 \pmod{57}$, and $2^9 \equiv -1 \pmod{57}$.